# In anylogic, how to set an agent in main to the top level

Tags: anylogic

I want to simulate my program. But I found that simulation can't change the variable in Main. It can only change variables in the top level. So how can I set my agent to the top level?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the control from the controls palette and put it in "main". With them you can change the values of any variable you want.
For example with a slider, you can change the variable using the "link to" option as you see in the following image:
[image: slider]